# Pivotting multiple columns with literal names_pattern

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to `pivot_longer()` my data frame to contain a column with the row number of the original data. Consider the following data frame:

```
set.seed(0)

df <- data.frame(
  a = runif(3),
  b = runif(3),
  c = runif(3)
) %>% mutate("row_id" = row_number())


> df
          a         b         c row_id
1 0.8966972 0.5728534 0.8983897      1
2 0.2655087 0.9082078 0.9446753      2
3 0.3721239 0.2016819 0.6607978      3
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
   name   value  row_id
   <chr>  <dbl>  <int>
 1 a      0.897  1
 2 b      0.573  1
 3 c      0.898  1
 4 a      0.266  2
 5 b      0.908  2
 6 c      0.945  2
 7 a      0.372  3
 8 b      0.202  3
 9 c      0.661  3
```

After reading `?pivot_longer` I tried to accomplish this by specifying `names_pattern` and `names_to` in the following way:

```
result <- df %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(
  cols = everything(),
  names_to = c(".value", "row_id"),
  names_pattern = "(.)([row_id])"
)
```

But end up with an output I don't really understand:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  row_id     r
  <chr>  <int>
1 NA        NA
2 o          1
3 NA        NA
4 o          2
5 NA        NA
6 o          3
```

I thought `[row_id]` should define a column by it's literal name. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I think the OP asked specifically about the `names_pattern` and `names_to`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need to specify the pattern here.  Just use the `cols` to select or deselect (`-`).  In this case, it makes more sense to deselect the 'row_id'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -row_id)
```

It can also be written as

```
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = a:c)
```

Or a regex pattern as name with `matches` or some of the `select_helpers`

```
df %>%
   pivot_longer(cols= matches('^[a-c]$'))
```